# The GET method is not supported for route admin/categories. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, laravel

I have been having this error no matter what i do.

This is the web.php page. I tried to creat a form that would add a product, when I tried to a an item it would show me this. I am new to laravel and don't have a clue about this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin.auth'],function(){

        // Categories Routes
        Route::get('/categories/create',[CategoryController::class,'create'])->name('categories.create');
        Route::post('/categories',[CategoryController::class,'store'])->name('categories.store');

        
    });
```

CategoryController.php

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {

    }

    public function create() {
        return view('admin.category.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $validator =Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'name' => 'required',
            'slug' =>'required|unique:categories',
        ]);

        if ($validator->passes()) {
            
            $category = new Category();
            $category->name = $request->name;
            $category->slug = $request->slug;
            $category->status = $request->status;
            $category->save();

            return response()->json([
                'status' => true,
                'message' => 'Category Added Successfully'
            ]);

            $request->session()->flash('success','Category Added Successfully');

        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => false,
                'errors' => $validator->error()
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

ajax that is used inside the form blade to enter the name and slug of the product

```
$.ajax({
        url: '{{ route("categories.store") }}',
        type: 'post',
        data: element.serializeArray(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){

            if (response["status"] == true) {

                $("#name").removeClasss('is-invalid')
                    .siblings('p')
                    .removeClass('invalid-feedback').html("");
                
                $("#slug").removeClasss('is-invalid')
                .siblings('p')
                .removeClass('invalid-feedback').html("");
                
            } else {
                var errors = response['errors'];
                if (errors['name']) {
                    $("#name").addClasss('is-invalid')
                    .siblings('p')
                    .addClass('invalid-feedback').html(errors['name']);
                } else {
                    $("#name").removeClasss('is-invalid')
                    .siblings('p')
                    .removeClass('invalid-feedback').html("");
                }
                
                if (errors['slug']) {
                    $("#slug").addClasss('is-invalid')
                    .siblings('p')
                    .addClass('invalid-feedback').html(errors['slug']);
                } else {
                    $("#slug").removeClasss('is-invalid')
                    .siblings('p')
                    .removeClass('invalid-feedback').html("");
                }
            }


        }, error: function(jqXHR, exception){
            console.log("Something went wrong");
        }
    })
```

Comment: show the blade form route.
or if using ajax then the URL route

Comment: You are most likely using GET when submitting your form instead of POST.

Comment: Did you define a route for the URL `admin/categories` anywhere that would be accessible through GET? `Route::post('/categories'....)` would not be that one

Comment: `$request->session()->flash(...)` _after_ a `return` makes no sense

Comment: Oriloe asks: *"does the 'categories.create' route display your form? if so, where is the storen route used by the form when it is submitted?"*

Answer (score 0):

With the way you are going, lets setup what you got for now more cleanly.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin.auth'],function(){
    // Categories Routes - index, create, store
    Route::resource('/categories', CategoryController::class)->only(['index', 'create', 'store']);

   /** 
    * A bit of info regarding the web resource
    * Actions Handled By Resource Controller
    * Verb          URI                     Action  Route Name
    * GET           /photos                 index   photos.index
    * GET           /photos/create          create  photos.create
    * POST          /photos                 store   photos.store
    * GET           /photos/{photo}         show    photos.show
    * GET           /photos/{photo}/edit    edit    photos.edit
    * PUT/PATCH     /photos/{photo}         update  photos.update
    * DELETE        /photos/{photo}         destroy photos.destroy
    */
});
```

Considering this, in your terminal inside the project, you can type:

```
php artisan route:list
```

This will show you all the available routes you have.
To debug if your code works, you can (inside the controller functions) do `dump('Dump.');` or `dd('Dump and die.)`.
This way you can see if you hit the endpoints you have created.

If you inspect the page and go to the "Network" tab, you can see what response you get

Now, regarding your ajax call. Its not recommended to get routes and parse them into JS (See `url: '{{ route("categories.store") }}'`). And for troubleshooting it, try writing the path manually that you got from the `route:list`.

Another tip is that ajax has `$.post()` available.

Hopefully, this will set you on the right path.

UPDATE:
I assume your query is run when you register an onclick using jquery as well. As such:

```
$("button").click(function(){ YourAjaxCallHere });
```